# Nested query in elastic

Tags: elasticsearch, subquery

Given the following simple Document:

```
{
   time: 1234545455,
   value: 50.6,
   unit: 'test'
}
```

I want to find all entries that have the same timestamp as entries with some specific unit. In pseudo-sql I´m looking for the query:

```
SELECT * from xyz WHERE time IN (SELECT time from xyz WHERE unit = 'some-unit')
```

How can this be done in ElasticSearch?

Comment: is it similar like to this "select * from xyz where unit = 'some-unit'" ?

Comment: No, it is not. Lets say each seconds there are 3 documents saved. There are recorded 3 values: {time: 123, value: some-value, unit: bar}, {time: 123, value: some-value2, unit: foo}, {time: 123, value: some-value3, unit: blubb}. Now i want to select all elements with the same timestamp, where value = some-value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **aggregation with filters** to get times, and using the results, do second query to fetch the documents.

**First query to get the relevant time**

```
  "size" : 0,
  "aggs" : {
    "relevant_time": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "match": {
                "unit": "some-unit"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "filterd_time": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "time"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

**For second query**, Iterate over the buckets returns and use the relevant_time in term query to fetch the whole document(s).

Comment: Thank you. This would work, but what if there are 1000+ results in the first query? That would mean that for the second query the number of executed queries = number of results from the first one. Is it a good design decission to issue that many queries?

Comment: yea @Alex, i know this is not good design. but here , you don't have to query 1000+ times. it will be 2 only (for less then 1000 results), iterate over <1000 results, create a list/set and pass it to terms in second query. One thing you will have to keep it mind is terms query with more then 1000 will not work, if your first query returns more then 1000 "value", you will have to batch it in size of 1000 and then call second query in loop. eg. if first query return 100,000 "value" , then second query will be executed, 100,000/1000 = 100 times. so total query will be 1 + 100.

Comment: In terms query, the no. of terms you can give has upper limit of 1000, so if you give more then 1000 inside terms query, then it will give error.